# White mold (?) in wooden bench's crevices: how to test and clean

Tags: wood, cleaning

I have a wooden bench that by design has crevices and recently I have noticed white mold-like things in these crevices:

[image]

How do I tell if this is mold or not? In any case, how I properly care for these wood furniture pieces?

Comment: Is the black material metal?

Comment: @Willk It is wood as well I am pretty sure.

Comment: Swab with a q-tip to see if it comes off.

Comment: @jeffcates Thanks. Will do and come back to update. Should I dip the tips in anything that is effective against mold and appropriate for wood?

Comment: I would just wipe with a clean q-tip first. If it comes off, try bleach to kill it. If it is metal and rust, then you will have to clean it good, prime and paint.

Answer (score 1):

I think that dark strip is a metal spacer.  I think the white stuff is [white rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_storage_stain)

[image]

https://www.sharrettsplating.com/blog/corrosion-resistance-of-zinc-plating/

White rust is zinc oxide forming on galvanized iron.
Test the strip with a magnet.  If I am right it is magnetic.   If that is the case there is no way that is mold.  The white stuff can be removed by scrubbing.  Wikipedia recommends oil to prevent white rust. I suspect that furniture polish could probably do double duty and protect the metal from oxidation as well.